# change bubble text postion in bubble chart android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

In Bubble chart text is shown in inside a bubble ,I want it show above that bubble not inside bubble, So how can I change text position of that text ?

it dose not have any method like bar view.

```
mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
```

Comment: there is no Bubble class in android SDK

Comment: @pskink  take a look at https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: so its open source, what stops you to change the sources and add `setDrawValueAboveBar` method?

Comment: that method is for barchart not for bubble chart.